# gecoder module works fine in the code, but is not found in udf pyspark running in virtual env for python

Tags: python, pyspark, python-venv

I created virtual env in python and I installed gecoder, on it.

I try to run this:

```
import geocoder
def get_lat_long(address):
    g = geocoder.osm(address, method='reverse')

    if g.ok:
        location = g.json
        return (location.get('lat', 0), location.get('lng', 0))
    else:
        return (0, 0)

# Define a UDF that returns a StructType with two DoubleType fields
get_lat_long_udf = udf(get_lat_long, StructType([
    StructField("latitude", DoubleType(), False),
    StructField("longitude", DoubleType(), False)
]))


# Apply the UDF to create two columns in the DataFrame
df_2 = df.withColumn("lat_long_osm", get_lat_long_udf(df["address_cleansed"]))

# Split the StructType column into two separate columns
df_2 = df_2.withColumn("latitude_osm", df_2["lat_long_osm"].getField("latitude"))
df_2 = df_2.withColumn("longitude_osm", df_2["lat_long_osm"].getField("longitude"))

# Drop the intermediate column "lat_long_osm" if not needed
df_2 = df_2.drop("lat_long_osm")
```

when I try to run df_2.show() i get the previous error, despite the fact that it ran yesterday on colab

when I try to do this:

```
g = geocoder.osm(address, method='reverse')
print(g)
```

it works as expected meaning it can see geocoder. Also, I tried to run the udf function in colab it works fine. I don't know what to check on my machine especially the module is installed and the other line outside of the udf works fine.
Any help please?

Comment: What is the error?